# HBase does not run after ./start-hbase.sh - Permission Denied?

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, hbase, permission-denied

I want to run HBase. I have installed hadoop completely and when I run `start-all.sh` , it works fine and gives me this output:

```
hduser@CSLAP106:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ jps
11956 SecondaryNameNode
12046 JobTracker
12193 TaskTracker
11800 DataNode
11656 NameNode
12254 Jps
```

But when I want to run `start-hbase.sh` , it gives me some errors of **permission denied** which I do not understand why:

```
hduser@CSLAP106:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin$ ./start-hbase.sh
localhost: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-zookeeper-CSLAP106.out

localhost: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 150: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-zookeeper-CSLAP106.log: Permission denied

localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-zookeeper-CSLAP106.out’ for reading: No such file or directory

/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 150: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.log: Permission denied

head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.out’ for reading: No such file or directory

localhost: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-regionserver-CSLAP106.out

localhost: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 150: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-regionserver-CSLAP106.log: Permission denied

localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-regionserver-CSLAP106.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

after that, I tried to run `sudo ./start-hbase.sh` , and I got something more weird!

```
root@localhost's password:
```

I do not know **what I am supposed to type here**. anyway I just clicked **Enter** and it switched back to `hduser` again:

```
root@localhost's password: 
root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.

root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.

localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-root-  master-CSLAP106.out
root@localhost's password: 
root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.

root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.

localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
hduser@CSLAP106:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin$
```

I put some lines from my `hbase-env.sh` and `hbase-site.xml` files in case they are needed:

**hbase-env.sh**

```
# File naming hosts on which HRegionServers will run.  $HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers by    default.
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/conf/regionservers

# File naming hosts on which backup HMaster will run.  $HBASE_HOME/conf/backup-masters by default.
export HBASE_BACKUP_MASTERS=/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/conf/backup-masters

# Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

So, what do you think is wrong with HBase that it does not run! I am really getting exhausted with this. It has been weeks I am working on it and every time it comes up with a new error. I would really appreciate your time and effort to help me :)

Comment: have you run it with sudoers?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Excuse me but I am kinda new in this, what do you mean by `sudoers`? If you mean the `sudo command`, yes, I ran it with sudo command and it asked me for `root localhost password` which I do not know. I included the code in my post.

Comment: oh...try to set password for your root user..your root user doesn;t have password yet.after that run your script

Comment: here is a link to help:(http://askubuntu.com/questions/155278/how-do-i-set-the-root-password-so-i-can-use-su-instead-of-sudo)

Comment: @MortezaLSC: But isn't it kinda dangerous to set password for the root user? You know, when I run `start-all.sh` for hadoop, it does not require any `sudo` command from me and it runs right away. But I do not know why when I type `start-hbase.sh` , it gives me **permission denied** error!

Comment: @MortezaLSC: thank you for the link. It is also mentioned in the link that `setting root password is like playing with fire`

Comment: ok..try it : sudo chmod +x start-hbase.sh and then do : ./start-hbase.sh

Comment: I know this is playing with fire..if my answer was correct tell me to put is in answer and please accept it

Comment: @MortezaLSC: I tried it! It still does not work and gives me the **permission denied** error :(

Comment: lotfan azash ls -l begirid va baram befrestid ...

Comment: @MortezaLSC: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1872 huhti  4  2013 start-hbase.sh`

Comment: do it: ls -l start-hbase.sh, you must make it executable...by : chmod +x start-hbase.sh or chmod 777 start-hbase.sh..after that sudo ./start-hbase.sh to run it

Comment: so..owner user and owner group is root...pay attention to this.you must run it with root user not even sudoers...if you want to run it just login as root or change user and group owner by typing chown command

Comment: try: chown hduser:hduser start-hbase.sh and then the hduser must be in sudoers list.but may be this is not needed to be in sudoers list..and after that : sudo ./start-hbase.sh

Comment: @MortezaLSC: I commanded `chmod 777 start-hbase.sh` . Now the `ls -l` looks like this : `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1872 huhti  4  2013 start-hbase.sh` - After that I typed `sudo ./start-hbase.sh` , **again** it requires the root password! Why is that? It's becoming irritating!! [BTW, Before asking this question, I tried to run `sudo sh ./start-hbase.sh` . After running this command, it started to ask for the root password!]

Comment: no...don;t lose your concentration...follow me(http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership) the problem is owner of script..root(user) and root(group)..read the link..and my previous comment

Comment: @MortezaLSC: `hduser@CSLAP106:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin$ chown hduser:hduser start-hbase.sh` - Output: `chown: invalid group: ‘hduser:hduser’`

Comment: @MortezaLSC: OK, thank you very much. I will read it and see if I can make it work!

Comment: see: you should know what user and group you have,,,I said hduser:hduser just as an example...if you set root password and run the script it woulp work very good...but use root user for just this scirpt..after that forget your root user...there shouldn't be problem

Comment: Did you understand where your problem is?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Still no result! If you look at my code in the main post, when I execute `./start-hbase.sh` , it starts to run but gives me error on `Line 150,151,152` of `hbase.daemon.sh` . So I think the problem is not with executing the `start-hbase.sh` itself, but with the code it is trying to access. Don't you think?

Comment: didn't work with (ROOT) user?

Comment: I don't know what this script do at line 130 for example.In the eyse of me the problem must be about owner of your script...and some files that doent exist because of (no such file errors)- pardon

Comment: once you can test: don't fear..(sudo su...then ./start-hbase.sh)

Comment: @MortezaLSC: I will try to set password for root, and see what happens

Comment: before setting passwd for root///try to be root with "sudo su" or "sudo bash"command

Comment: please add comment on my answer below..thank you

Comment: @MortezaLSC: OK, I will. I'm working on it now.

Comment: is every thing ok? I insist because you are fellow country

Comment: @MortezaLSC: I changed the root password. HBase seems to be running alright. It just tells me that regionserver is running and I should stop it first. Anyway, it is working without errors. Thank you very much :)

Comment: your welcome...you could be root without setting password for it..by sudo su or sudo bash...

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Actually the problem was that I did something(I do not know what :P ), which cause the `sudo su` not to work!! No sudo command worked! That was why I changed the root password because it has been set to something else that I could not remember! And then it worked!

Comment: ok...good..I think you are not high experienced person in linux..no problem..step by step...

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Yup, I'm new in this. It's been few months I'm learning and I think I have chosen a big thing to do for an amateur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you say the output of ls -l start-hbase.sh is :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1872 huhti 4 2013 start-hbase.sh
```

if you want to know what user and group you are logging with , there us simple way:

```
touch test
ls -l test
```

and check user:group ...

the problem is user owner and group owner of script..
you have two solutions:

```
1) sudo chown hduser:hduser start-hbase.sh  #here hduser is example...you should know what user and group you have,,,
```

inorder to make it your slave...with executable state(`sudo chmod +x start-hbase.sh`)

```
2) you can be root by: "su root" or "sudo su" or "sudo bash"
```

and then execute the script...

Comment: the first solution works as well...you need to know what your user ang group is...a solution is by touching file and see the result of ls -l...your welcome

Comment: no,,,linux is so sweet...pay attention that first solution was possible as well..just need to know what user ang group your are at...

Comment: Yeah,I'm really starting to like working with it. I have encountered a problem again! When I run `start-hbase.sh` it shows that it is logging to the `master`, `zookeeper` and `regionserver`, and without any errors, it logs in. But when I type `jps`, I see `Hregionserver` but not `HMaster`. And when I run `localhost: 60010` in my browser, it does not show anything :(

Comment: which distro are you using? centos? ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10
The funny thing is that, after I have started hbase, now I want to stop it, but it does not stop, nor does it show the output I want! Do I need to do another installation and start everything from the scratch? The problem is that there is no one who has worked with hadoop and hbase before around me, and I have to do this project!

Comment: Isn't this weird?: stopping hbase
root@CSLAP106:~# jps
17155 HMaster
17248 Jps
6806 HRegionServer ... It says it is stopping, but still shows HMaster and HRegionServer!

Comment: I think I have to start everything from the beginning! It is not working maybe because I have done some changes to some parts and I am not aware of them! You know, it's been 2 months I am working on this, and I could not even get the single node cluster to work properly!

Comment: I haven't worked with hbase.but generally if you want to stop a script you should kill the process(ps aux | grep script.sh)--then see the process id.after that:(kill -9 <pid>)===if 60010 doesn't work you should work with firewall and allow this port.now for pass this problem do(sudo ufw disable)

Comment: ask your new problem in this site someone would help you

Comment: Yes,sure. Thank you for your help all through the way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problem after changing the permission of start-hbase.sh then run following command

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hbase
```

Give permission to 'hbase' directory to write log file..

I hope this will help to other folks...