# ./start-hbase.sh is not starting on stand alone

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, hbase

```
root@sujit-pc:/usr/local/hbase/bin# ./start-hbase.sh
./start-hbase.sh: line 48: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase: Permission denied
./start-hbase.sh: line 55: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemons.sh: Permission denied
./start-hbase.sh: line 56: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: Permission denied
./start-hbase.sh: line 57: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemons.sh: Permission denied
./start-hbase.sh: line 59: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemons.sh: Permission denied
root@sujit-pc:/usr/local/hbase/bin#
```

I think, there is some permission issue. But i am already on root

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166542/hbase-does-not-run-after-start-hbase-sh-permission-denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod 777 ./start-hbase.sh` to allow r/w access for all users.

`chmod +x ./start-hbase.sh` to make the script executable.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I ran both commands still same problem is there. 
I have installed java, hadoop, hbase.
is there need of installing other tools as well ?? e.g. zookeeper

Comment: I made a mistake; you should be running those commands on the `hbase-daemons.sh` file. If that doesn't work, try running them recursively on the hbase folder (using the `-R` option)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot comment cause less than 50 rep. What does ls -l start-hbase.sh return?

Btw have a look on [HBase does not run after ./start-hbase.sh - Permission Denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166542/hbase-does-not-run-after-start-hbase-sh-permission-denied)

Comment: root@sujit-pc:/usr/local/hbase/bin#  ls -l start-hbase.sh
-rwx--x--x 1 sujit sujit 1986 Mar 17 09:25 start-hbase.sh

Comment: i gone through your mentioned  link , being on root does not solve my problem. as u can i see i am already on root.

Comment: just to be sure you own it. Hmm ok how about hbase-daemons.sh? maybe chmod 777 it all :D just to find the issue